# ASM x86 integer overflow

Tags: html, assembly, x86

```
GetLCM PROC
tryAgain:
   mov bx, 0
   inc Multiple
   mov ax, UserInputNum1              ;Move UserInputNum1 to the 16 bit Register
   mov bx, Multiple
   div bx                             ;<-------Error here
   cmp dx,0                           ;If dx is not zero then there is a remainder
   jne tryAgain                       ;If not equal jump
ret
GetLCM ENDP
```

I keep getting a integer overflow error when trying to div these two numbers. It breaks when i try to use div.

I am trying to find the least common multiple of two numbers entered by the user. I decided to try to divide each number to find prime numbers first then compare each time one is found to the other number the user entered. Of course I would be doing both numbers at the same time, but as of now I am trying to just get past this error.

This is only my fifth week in ASM so I am a little confuse why this is happening.
Also I would like to add that I would also like to make this work for 32bit numbers as well. My idea is to use pointers. Is this a good way to do this?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just an algorithmic remark: `lcm(a,b) = a*b/gcd(a,b)`, that's _much_ faster than finding primes dividing either of the numbers.

Comment: In order to do assembly, you need to have your architecture's manuals handy, e.g. [Intel's x86 Instruction Set Reference](http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/24319101.pdf). 16-bit `DIV` works on `DX:AX`. Your `DX` has not been set. To do 32-bit, just reference 32-bit register mnemonics, `EAX`, `ECX`, etc.

Comment: Again someone who forgot that `div` is double-width. Apparently it doesn't show up in the suggested questions when asking about it. Can't something be done about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on the `div` instruction again. What is divided by what? You are missing to set one of the operands to some sensible value.

Answer (score 5):

`xor dx, dx` somewhere before your `div`

Comment: Thanks I forgot to initialize dx to 0