# divide emu 8086 assembly error

Tags: assembly, x86-16, divide-by-zero

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASM x86 integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391152/asm-x86-integer-overflow)

I get a divide error- overflow  and am not sure why.
Here is the complete code that reproduces the error

```
include emu8086.inc

org 100h

       mov ax, 2 
       mov bx, 10
       div bx

       mov ax, 2
       mov bx, 2
       div bx   
       ret
```

Comment: For division by power of 2, shift is usually used. It is much simplier to use SHR AX, 1 - no need to use extra register.

Answer (score 11):

Try adding `xor dx, dx` before each `div` and see if that doesn't help.

Since you're specifying a 16-bit target, `div` divides `dx:ax` by that target. If `dx` starts out containing a large number (more accurately, anything but quite a small number), the result will overflow. Even if it doesn't overflow, your result won't just be `ax`/`bx` as you apparently intend.

Comment: thanks for the quick response and explanation. worked perfectly