# How to draw the square root in emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am trying to do a calculation in emu8086, however there doesn't seem to be a root function available, I have been trying to make it myself, and I think I got it, however i'm getting errors on two lines:

```
  ;si is the number that I need the square root of.
  mov bx, 0   ;sets the cycle to start at 0
  mov dx, si  ;moves the number into dx for processing
  sqrt:       ;the loop, it continues as long as bx < si/2
  mov ax, si  ;from here starts this formula: x = (x + n / x) / 2
  div dx      ;I am getting a divide error -overflow here
  add ax, dx  
  mov ch, 2
  div ch      ;the same divide error -overflow here
  mov dx, ax
  mov ax, si
  mov ch, 2
  div ch
  cmp bx, ax  ;the formula repeats until bx = si/2
  jl sqrt
  cmp bx, ax  ; if bx = si/2, exit the loop.
  jge cnt:

  ;sqrt si
  cnt:
  mov si, dx
```

why are the two errors showing up?

Comment: You have to make sure that when you place the new divided number that the target container in your cases `dx` and `ch` can hold the amount of bits that div returns. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941631/divide-emu-8086-assembly-error

Comment: No FPU support in emu8086?  FSQRT would do what you want if emu8086 supports the FPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16-bit division operation in `8086` uses the 32 bit value formed by the contents of registers `DX:AX` as dividend, the quotient is returned in `AX` and the remainder in `DX`. If the quotient is too big to fit in 16 bits, an `INT 0` happens.

So when you are doing:

```
mov ax, si  ;from here starts this formula: x = (x + n / x) / 2
div dx      ;I am getting a divide error -overflow here
```

You are dividing not the value of `AX` by `DX`, but the value of `DX:AX` by `DX`. As `DX` begins with a copy of `SI`, as well as `AX` does, your dividend is `SI*65536+SI`.

`SI*65536+SI` divided by `SI` yields `65537`, which is bigger than `AX` can hold, hence, division error.

About this one:

```
mov ch, 2
div ch      ;the same divide error -overflow here
```

8-bit division uses `AX` as dividend, returning the quotient in `AL` and remainder in `AH`. Once again, if the quotient is too big for `AL`, an overflow happens. In your case, the overflow will happen whenever `AX` has a value equal or bigger than `512`.

Comment: is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I guess so. Don't use register DX to hold values, and set it to zero just before the first division. For the second division, use 16-bit division to ensure that there won't be overflow in the quotient.