# assembly: I can't do division by 10 of 9801

Tags: assembly

I have this code:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
.CODE
.STARTUP
        MOV AX, 9801d

        MOV BH, 0d
        MOV BL, 10d

        DIV BL
    END
```

In summary, it divides by 10 what is present in the AX register, it works beautifully for some values, but for others, for example 9801 it doesn't work, when I run it it goes into a loop, while when I run the debugger it returns the following error:

```
 divide error - overflow.
 to manually process this error,
 change address of INT 0 in interrupt vector table.
```

I promise I'm new, so sorry if the error is due to a lack of me, thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [divide emu 8086 assembly error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941631/divide-emu-8086-assembly-error)

Comment: Ages since I've done anything in assembler, but doesn't DIV BL store the quotient in AL and remainder in AH? 9801/10=980, which is too big for AL?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, right observation, so what should I do?

Comment: You could do DX:AX div BX. That means you'd have to set DX to 0 as well

Comment: @Michael Petch, could you give me an example?

Comment: `MOV AX, 9801d` `XOR DX, DX` `MOV BX, 10d` `DIV BX`. That will take the 32-bit value in DX:AX (0x00009801) and divide it by BX (0x10). The 16-bit quotient will be in AX and the 16-bit remainder will be in DX. Note: XORing a register with itself has the same effect at setting that register to 0